# Find array length in 8086 assembly

Tags: arrays, assembly, x86-16

Is there an easy way to find an array length in 8086 assembly language, or is this something that should be known ahead of time?

Comment: Either it's known ahead of time, or else there's some sort of "terminator", such as C's null-terminated strings. There's no built-in concept of an array's length at machine-code level, though individual assembly languages are at liberty to define such a concept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the array is defined locally, you can use LENGTHOF (number of elements), or SIZEOF (number of bytes):

```
str     db      'example string',0dh,0ah,00h
; ...
        lea     ebx,str
        mov     ecx,sizeof str
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.data
  arr dw 3h,1h,2h 
  count = ($-arr)
.code
mov ax,count      ;will contain the length , here is 6
```